# Adapting a Win8 store app tutorial to WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=m-EqckhJNvI) that explains how to create a Dial in Visual Studio with XAML/C#. The problem is that the tutorial is targeted for windows 8 store apps.

Knowing that, I still tried to use this tutorial in a WPF application that will support previous OSs too.

I came across a few compatibility problems:

1. `ManipulationMode="All"` doesn't exists as the author of the tutorial uses it for me. It only exists as `Manipulation.ManipulationMode="All"` which gives me an error "Manipulation is not active on the specified element". How could I solve it?
2. The author set the `ManipulationDelta` property on the `grid` element, which I didn't have problem with at first... Until I realized the author's event/action code-behind created by VS uses `ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e` instead of the `ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e` which is used in my code-behind file. This means I can't use the `Position` property (`e.Position`) to get the mouse position on the user control as easily. What could be an alternative to it? I don't think it could be supported as it was declared as Win8 only...
3. In an MVVM-style application, the code-behind actions would have been set in the `ViewModel`. How would I 'bind' that action code to the `ManipulationDelta` property of an element?

Thanks in advance!

P.S; Both mine and the author's version of VS is 2012 so that's not the problem.

UPDATE:
Here's the partially-completed code:

The XAML:

```
//Manipulation.ManipulationMode="All" => ERROR 'Manipulation is not active on the specified element'
<Grid Manipulation.ManipulationMode="All" ManipulationDelta="Grid_ManipulationDelta_1">
    <Ellipse Fill="#FF7171E6" Margin="30"/>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform CenterX="225" CenterY="225" Angle="{Binding Angle}"/>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
        <Ellipse Fill="White" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="50" Width="100"/>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The code-behind:

```
public partial class dial : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int m_Amount;
    public int Amount {...}

    private double m_Angle;
    public double Angle {...}

    public dial()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void Grid_ManipulationDelta_1(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Angle = GetAngle(e.Position, this.RenderSize); //e.Position doesn't exist in ManipulationDeltaEventArgs...
        this.Amount = (int)(this.Angle / 360 * 100);
    }

    public enum Quadrants : int { nw = 2, ne = 1, sw = 4, se = 3 }
    private double GetAngle(Point touchPoint, Size circleSize)
    {
        var _X = touchPoint.X - (circleSize.Width / 2d);
        var _Y = circleSize.Height - touchPoint.Y - (circleSize.Height / 2d);
        var _Hypot = Math.Sqrt(_X * _X + _Y * _Y);
        var _Value = Math.Asin(_Y / _Hypot) * 180 / Math.PI;
        var _Quadrant = (_X >= 0) ?
            (_Y >= 0) ? Quadrants.ne : Quadrants.se :
            (_Y >= 0) ? Quadrants.nw : Quadrants.sw;
        switch (_Quadrant)
        {
            case Quadrants.ne: _Value = 090 - _Value; break;
            case Quadrants.nw: _Value = 270 + _Value; break;
            case Quadrants.se: _Value = 090 - _Value; break;
            case Quadrants.sw: _Value = 270 + _Value; break;
        }
        return _Value;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}
```

Comment: I would look into this, but I'm not going to watch a 15 minute video tutorial to figure out what is going on. Do you have a link to the source code or something?

Comment: Nope, that's the problem. I did however write some of it so I will update my post

Comment: @xTCx - It sounds like you will have to take a new approach to recreate the dial and the code for a WinRT Windows Store application cannot be used.

Comment: Hmm... I see. What could be the way though? I'm new to WPF so I'm trying to learn... Basically, all I need to know is how to get the X,Y coordinates of the mouse in the **user control**. I could take it from there...

Answer (score 1):

1. In WPF, you can use IsManipulationEnabled="true" to enable manipulation. Don't need to use                ManipulationMode="All" like Windows store app.
2. You can try Mouse.GetPosition(this) to get current  mouse position